# How to pass arguments with Axis2 webservice URL?

Tags: web-services, url, apache-axis, argument-passing

I have created a web service interface with Axis2, and it's working well. However, I want to pass arguments with the url pattern from the client side, so that I can make use of them in the service side (like "..//ADDRESS:PORT/service/ServiceName?ARGUMENT=123").

Can any one help me to achieve this?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dispatcher class and implement in its 'invoke' method a 
functionality which parses the URL, and then pass the arguments to your 
service.